# RAW Attacking a surface with Damage (Contagious, Increased Mass 8+) for pseudo AoE?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

With the wording "Contagious effects work on both the target and anyone coming into contact with the target" (pg. 192) it implies the initial target does not need to be a character, and Increased Mass says the mass influenced when targeting objects, which for attacks is implied to be 50 lbs at first if we use the Attack Extra as reference. Would giving an attack Contagious and Increased Mass (pg. 193) cause the area applicable for Contagion to increase via the amount of surface the effect is applied to to increase?

I was thinking about a Earthquaking Punch for the next boss, but there was no surface based areas that I could find other than this, and this at least seems neat as a tech if it is possible (albeit a bit scary given contagion goes straight to the resistance check if I'm looking at it right).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer your second question, in that the core book already has an example of an Area that only affects ground-based enemies, as seen on the Powerhouse archetype.

> **Groundstrike**: Burst Area Affliction 10 (Resisted by Fortitude; Vulnerable, Defenseless), Instant Recovery, Limited Degree, Limited: Both the Powerhouse and its targets must be in contact with the ground

This is the first time I've seen someone trying to use Contagious on an inanimate surface. It's an interesting academic answer. FWIW, as a GM, I'd probably look askance at someone trying to use it that way, but as we've discussed before, Rule 0 means you could allow this in your game if you'd like.

I did ask Steve Kenson about the use of Contagious on inanimate objects, and [he pointed out that it's highly dependent on descriptors](https://www.youtube.com/live/hSXCg1e2lNI?si=wan5ddlCZGIscZIs&t=973). A stone wall isn't likely to get infected with a disease. A body of water isn't going to catch fire. They then said that if the intent was to attack multiple people, an Area modifier would make more sense.

Comment: Happy that you're asking them because I found out too late the stream was mid workday for me. Similar to previous talks I'm looking for RAW answers not relying on Rule 0, since emergent gameplay is cool to me and I'd rather not use that as a means of resolving debate on the subject with my players. Some plague esc encounters in my server actually use Triggered 8: On Contact with character *with* Contagious, where the Affliction/Damage applies whenever the initial target(s) comes in contact with the character, though that's probably a question for another time.

Comment: Suppose all that's left is the Increased Mass part of the question, given the rules on how much mass damage applies to is a bit funky.

Comment: So I've come back around to maybe asking a similar question though I figured "hey why not ask Sean on the existing post", is this implying that attacking the ground beneath a target within 5 ft of you allows a effect to spread to a target without a additional attack check of hitting them? Might make this its own question since power crit attacking the ground in 5 ft of a target as part of a multiattack could potentially do some weird stuff with the power stunt part of critting.

Comment: @FriendlyNeighborhoodChicken: Truthfully? I think Contagious is probably vaguely worded because Steve had more of the idea of accidental contact. Just spitballing things, for people trying to spread the contagion, it's a close (probably Unarmed) attack. For incidental contact, it's a Dodge save against the effect rank before the save against effect.